# Google Docs API and Dreaded Table Row Inserts

Tags: google-docs-api

I've been playing around with Google Docs API and am stuck on being able to add a row to an existing table in a doc and fill that row (3 columns) with data.

Below is Pastebin file of Google Get which returns a huge JSON of pretty much everything in the doc (formatting, content etc.)

```
(Stack OVerflow has an issue with me including pastebin file so be ready for a huge file underneath here which probably won't fit)
```

This a sample doc - and if you check it out in a too like https://jsoneditoronline.org/ (which I just used) to see the document structure - you'll note that it has 3 tables in total.

I've written some code that puts the start indexes of all the tables in the document into an array but I can't for the life of me figure out a clear explanation of how I can:
a) Insert a row (at the bottom of the first table for example)
b) Insert data into the first, second and 3rd column of that new row

I have read the guides but it is all very confusing - because after I insert a row the document changes and the startIndexes and all that adjust - is that correct?

If anyone has any input on the code that would insert a new row AND populate the columns in that row in a one easy to use solution I would really appreciate any help (hopefully without having to query the whole JSON again after inserting the row).

Thank you
P.S. Tried to insert pastebin link but it wouldn't let me... tried to paste JSON directly and it was too big so... I'll have to leave the question with the most info I can for now - I will ask Google direct and include the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

just updating that I've solved this by using the FPDF PHP library instead - and I just copy the Google Docs text into this Google converter (conerts to HTML) then passing all the HTML to the FPDF library.

So... question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

For interested parties:

use DocumentService.BatchUpdateDocumentRequest()

request should be [InsertTableRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/docs/v1#InsertTableRowRequest)
for more information see: